# Having game sounds played through voice chat

Tags: keep-talking-and-nobody-explodes

My friend and I started streaming Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes and had the idea of making the game more intense for the bomb experts by playing back the game sound effects through voice comms so that the experts could hear the game sounds to.. motivate them. We had the idea to play the game sounds through speakers and have that go through the voice comms, but that's not viable because of his kids, so he can't have speakers on late at night. What would be the best way to make the game sounds go through voice comms to the experts? We tried to mix the audio channels but that also repeats the experts voice which is not desired.

Comment: Couldn't he just plug headphones into the spekers, so he wouldn't be disturbing the kids?

Comment: No, because the point was that the speakers would be loud enough so the game sounds come through his microphone.

Answer (score 1):

There is an audio mixing program online that you can use for something like this called VoiceMeeter Banana, available [here](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/banana.htm). This will allow you to add virtual sound inputs/outputs to connect audio sources together, meaning that you can use this to play the game sounds in conjuction with a person speaking on Skype through the same audio source.

My friend and I also use this when we play Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes, and it works perfectly.

Comment: We'll have to check that out next time we play, will report back if it works for us.

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote to Texenox's answer, I also suggest you get the Virtual Audio Cable and the Hi-Fi Cable. These will give you more options when it comes to setting up VoiceMeeter Banana.

For example, you can connect one of the Virtual Cables' input to Skype's sound output, feed the same cable's output into one of the hardware inputs, and then run that through the hardware output connected to your headphones.